# How to echo element of associative array in string?

Tags: php, associative-array

I know It's a very basic question but I have to ask.

I have an associative array let's say it is:

```
 $couple = array('husband' => 'Brad', 'wife' => 'Angelina');
```

Now, I want to print husband name in a string. There are so many ways but i want to do this way but it gives html error

```
$string = "$couple[\'husband\'] : $couple[\'wife\'] is my wife.";
```

Please correct me if I'm using a wrong syntax for backslash.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738850/interpolation-double-quoted-string-of-associative-arrays-in-php

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400018/syntax-error-unexpected-t-encapsed-and-whitespace-expecting-t-string-or-t-vari#13423474

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.

But, still you can prefer single quotes versus double quotes.

Because, double quotes are a bit slower due to variable interpolation.

(variables within double quotes are parsed, not the case for single quotes.)

A more optimized and cleaned version of your code:

```
$string = $couple['husband'] .' : ' . $couple['wife'] .' is my wife.';
```

Answer (score 1):

To use array in a string, you need to use {}:

```
$string = "{$couple['husband']} : {$couple['wife']} is my wife.";
```

Otherwise the parser cannot properly determine what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using output formatting string function such as [printf](http://php.net/printf)

```
<?php printf("%s : %s is my wife.", $couple['husband'], $couple['wife']); ?>
```

If you want store the output in a variable, you have to use `sprintf`.

Checkout this DEMO: http://codepad.org/kkgvvg4D

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php $string = $couple['husband']." : ". $couple['wife']." is my wife."; 
  echo  $string//Brad : Angelina is my wife.
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
$string = "{$couple['husband']} : {$couple['wife']} is my wife.";
```

Or:

```
$string = $couple['husband'] . " : " . $couple['wife'] . " is my wife.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$string = $couple['husband']." : ".$couple['wife']." is my wife.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the solution -

> `$string = "$couple[husband] : $couple[wife] is my wife.";`

as you can see you have to remove single quotes and backslashes if you are using the entire string inside double qoutes.

A much better approach will be -

> `$string = $couple[husband].' : '.$couple[wife].' is my wife.';`

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func_array('sprintf', array_merge(['%s : %s is my wife.'], $couple))
```