# "syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)" while using HEREDOC syntax in PHP7.2, but PHP7.4 is fine

Tags: php, runtime-error, syntax-error, heredoc

```
if (array_key_exists('icon_path', $changedAttributes)) {
    $iconFile = $changedAttributes["icon_path"];
}
```

Why does `$iconFile = $changedAttributes["icon_path"];` line gives me below error in **php 7.2**?
Even though I change it to single quotations  `['icon_path']` doesn't solve the problem.

```
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

But in **php 7.4** there's no problem at all.

I checked my code with this version checker
https://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/
7.2 gives me this error but 7.4 works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on that line?

Comment: Is it possible that `icon_path` is actually empty? Is might well _exist_ but if it's empty, you will be trying to access `$changedAttributes[""]` which of course will give you that error...

Comment: I presume something is missing somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Please, always show the real error message ALL OF IT and the real code, enough of that so we are sure we are looking at the right line in the right file :)

Comment: @Stuart in that case they should get some sort of runtime error (and more likely saying undefined index), but not a parse error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [syntax error, unexpected T\_ENCAPSED\_AND\_WHITESPACE, expecting T\_STRING or T\_VARIABLE or T\_NUM\_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400018/syntax-error-unexpected-t-encapsed-and-whitespace-expecting-t-string-or-t-vari)

Comment: I checked my code with this version checker https://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/
7.2 gives me this error but 7.4 works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HEREDOC interfering with code indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305869/heredoc-interfering-with-code-indentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an indent issue. My code has below JavaScript code.

```
public function reloadPageOnEdit()
{
    return <<<JSCRIPT
        <script>
            function openWindowReload(link) {
                var href = link.href;
                
                document.location.reload(true);
                window.open(href,'_self');
            }
        </script>
        JSCRIPT;
}
```

and I indented it fully left. It solved the problem. Even there's no issue in 7.4 but 7.2.
I got confused because the code failed on somewhere else.

```
    public function reloadPageOnEdit()
    {
        return <<<JSCRIPT
<script>
    function openWindowReload(link) {
        var href = link.href;
        
        document.location.reload(true);
        window.open(href,'_self');
    }
</script>
JSCRIPT;
    }
```

Comment: The script tags can be indented as you like. The only issue is with the identifier line `JSCRIPT;`. See the warning here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc This was changed in 7.3 so could be why you weren't seeing in 7.4.

Comment: @user3783243 thanks, properly indenting `JSCRIPT;` is enough.